# Return Statement is not working properly in recursive function of Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, graph-algorithm

Hi i have a python code for DFS algorithm. I need to return when i reached to "GoalNode". But my function don't return, it works until the reach all the nodes. I guess problem is i don't know how recursive function works. My function must stop in bolded code lines. How can i solve this problem

```
def DFS(visited, StartNode, GoalNode):
    index =(list(MainDictionary).index(StartNode))
    visited[index] = True
    print(StartNode)

    **# it has to return here out put must be only F - C but function reaches all the nodes
    if StartNode == GoalNode:
        return**

    #This line is for accessing my dictionary data type
    values = ReturnKeyVal(StartNode)
    for key in values:
        index =(list(values).index(key))
        if visited[index] == False and values[key] != 0:

            DFS(visited, key, GoalNode)

def ReturnKeyVal(Target):
    for keys, values in MainDictionary.items():
            if keys == Target:
                return values

visited = [False] * (len(MainDictionary)) 
DFS(visited,"F", "C")
```

Comment: Could you add your MainDictionary?

Answer (score 0):

While I have other questions about your code (Because I can't figure out what ReturnKeyVal is supposed to do, if MainDictionary is a normal python dictionary it would just return the value corresponding to the key but if you just wanted to do that why would you write a function for it? Getting the corresponding value is what keys are for. Which is why I asked for the MainDictionary.) the problem is pretty simple: You don't check whether a function call has found the goal so the loop will continue regardless of whether it has been found. The return just ends the current function call not the entire recursion. Return true if it is found and then check the return value and keep returning true.